# Plotting H5PY/HDF5 Data

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

Afternoon!
I'm trying to plot the following HDF5 data:

https://www.gw-openscience.org/eventapi/html/GWTC-1-confident/GW150914/v3/H-H1_GWOSC_4KHZ_R1-1126259447-32.hdf5

This returns the time (in seconds) and the strain (which has no units), with plot being the strain as a function of time.

However, the code so far doesn't work:

(I've renamed the file as "Hanford").
How do I do this?

The code I've tried, but says t is undefined. Not sure if I've successfully uploaded the h5py file.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import h5py as h5py

def loadLIGOdata(Hanford):
    f = h5py.File(Hanford, "r")
    strain = f['strain/Strain'][...]
    t0 = f['strain/Strain'].attrs['Xstart'] 
    dt = f['strain/Strain'].attrs['Xspacing'] 
    t = t0 + dt * np.arange(strain.shape[0]) 
    f.close()
    return t, strain

plt.plot(t, strain)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the 't' and 'strain' variables by calling your loadLIGOdata() function. From what you posted, Hanford also needs to be defined as a file path. The following should work after changing the file path to where Hanford is located on your computer.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import h5py as h5py

## Change to the path of your Hanford file ##
Hanford = '/path/to/Hanford'

def loadLIGOdata(Hanford):
    f = h5py.File(Hanford, "r")
    strain = f['strain/Strain'][...]
    t0 = f['strain/Strain'].attrs['Xstart'] 
    dt = f['strain/Strain'].attrs['Xspacing'] 
    t = t0 + dt * np.arange(strain.shape[0]) 
    f.close()
    return t, strain

t, strain = loadLIGOdata(Hanford)

plt.plot(t, strain)
plt.show()
```